# Shiny modules import data and hide html if success

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to know how it is possible with callModule() to hide html if my data are imported with a reactive boolean (boolmark)

Here's my code

ui.R

```
    shinyUI( 
    column(width=9,
            div( style = "width:100% ; max-width: 1200px; height: 100%" ,
    conditionalPanel(condition = 'output.boolmark', tags$(HTML code),
    conditionalPanel(condition = '!output.boolmark', code))
    div(id="pass",style = "word-wrap: break-word;",
        column(width = 3,
    csvFileInput("datafile", "User data (.csv format)"))
```

server.R

```
   shinyServer(
   csvf <- callModule(csvFile, "datafile",stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

csvmodules.R

```
   csvFileInput <- function(id, label = "CSV file") {
   ns <- NS(id)

   tagList(
     fileInput(ns("file"),multiple = T, label),
     checkboxInput(ns("heading"), "Has heading"),
    selectInput(
  ns("quote"),
  "Quote",
  c(
    "None" = "",
    "Double quote" = "\"",
    "Single quote" = "'"
  )))}

  csvFile <- function(input, output, session, stringsAsFactors) {

  showmark <<- T # Boolean uses to hide or show the mardkwon serving to load data

  userFile <- reactive({
# If no file is selected, don't do anything
validate(need(input$file, message = FALSE))})

output$boolmark <- reactive({
  showmark
})

observe({
  print(showmark)})
outputOptions(output,"boolmark",suspendWhenHidden=F) 


  csv <- lapply(
    csvtest,


    FUN = function (x)

      fread(data.table = F,check.names = F,
        header = T,sep = ";",dec = ","
      ) 
  )
  observe({
showmark <<-F
print(showmark)
}) # modify and lock the bool value to false

output$boolmark <- reactive({
  showmark
})
 return (csv)}
)}
```

Well, this code is working outside the module but the html is not hidden when using the modules

Why and how to fix it ?

Comment: Anyone? maybe im doing it wrong, should I code in the server.R and use the renderUI() function to return it to the ui.R ?

Comment: You should provide the module namespace to `conditionalPanel` (`conditionalPanel(..., ns = NS("datafile"))`) . Otherwise, `conditionalPanel` will look for the id `boolmark` only in the namespace of the "main app" .

Comment: Thanks a lot my good sir its working : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments the problem is that `conditionalPanel` needs to know in which namespace to look for the input- and output ids appearing in the `condition` argument. This can be done by passing the namespace function to `conditionalPanel`.

```
ns <- NS("datafile")
conditionalPanel("!output.boolmark", ns, ...)
```

A simplified and fixed version of your app could look like this:

```
library(shiny)

myModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  checkboxInput(ns("checkbox"), "checkbox")
}

myModule <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$value <- reactive({ input$checkbox })
  outputOptions(output, "value", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    myModuleUI("myModule"),
    conditionalPanel("output.value", ns = NS("myModule"), "checkbox is TRUE")
  ),
  function(input, output, session) {
    callModule(myModule, "myModule")
  }
)
```

Normally, it is not a good practice to refer to the module by id from outside the module so I would use the following adaptation.

```
myModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  checkboxInput(ns("checkbox"), "checkbox")
}

myModule <- function(input, output, session) {
  return(reactive({input$checkbox}))
}

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    myModuleUI("myModule"),
    conditionalPanel("output.value", "checkbox is TRUE")
  ),
  function(input, output, session) {
    output$value <- callModule(myModule, "myModule")
    outputOptions(output, "value", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  }
)
```

The general idea behind this is that you either want to implement the logic inside your module (call `conditionalPanel` in `myModuleUI`) or `return` a value from `myModule` that gives the main app the possibility to work with the reactive objects generated by the module.

Comment: You're doin' more than asnwering the question thanks for your explanation and time !